# Why is trivlist used in center, theorem and other environments?

Tags: vertical-alignment, amsthm

I've noticed that the `trivlist` environment is used in the AMS Theorem package and in the definition of the `center` environment. For example:

```
\def\center{\trivlist \centering\item\relax}
\def\endcenter{\endtrivlist}
```

(Source: http://texblog.net/latex-archive/floats/center-centering/)

The main consequence seems to be that `trivlist` adds vertical space above and below these environments.

Why is `trivlist` used in these definitions?

Comment: `trivlist` was used in `amsthm` mainly because the theorem facility in latex itself used `trivlist`.  (this is not universally considered a good choice, and there are unwanted side effects.)  the vertical space above and below the `plain` and `definition` theorem environments is not because of `trivlist`, but because the space is traditional in good mathematical typography.  the `remark` environment (a companion theorem-class environment) does *not* have additional space above and below.

Comment: `\trivlist` is a command from the LaTeX-kernel which is used for several environments like `center` in LaTeX. The difference to the more complex command `\list` (used in lists) is that there is no implementation for labels (for items) here. Well, it is just a command to add vertical space around some display elements in LaTeX. AMS is taking this command in order to get the same spacing as in other elements. You already answered your own question so I do not understand exactly its purpose.

Comment: @barbarabeeton An answer?

Answer (score 2):

`trivlist` was used in `amsthm` mainly because the theorem facility in latex
itself used `trivlist`. (this is not universally considered a good choice,
and there are unwanted side effects.)

the vertical space above and below the `plain` and `definition` theorem
environments is not because of `trivlist`, but because the space is
traditional in good mathematical typography.
the `remark` environment (a companion theorem-class environment) does not
have additional space above and below.

the creator of latex apparently saw nearly every slightly non-trivial
paragraph as a list element.  it's much too late to change this now, although
there may be hopes with latex3.